# Posting an object via REST XML in C# WCF returns 400 Bad request

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, rest

I'm trying to Post an object to a WCF Service using REST with XML, but I keep getting the `"error: (400) Bad Request"` thrown. I know there are a lot of posts on this site concerning the same problem, but I can't seem to find a solution.

**My WCF service code:**

**IPhoneBookService.cs:**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke( UriTemplate = "/addentry/", 
                Method = "POST",
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    void AddEntry(Contact contact);
```

**PhoneBookService.cs:**

```
    DataPhonebookDataContext dc = new DataPhonebookDataContext();
    public void AddEntry(Contact contact)
    {
        if (contact == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("contact");
        }
        dc.Contacts.InsertOnSubmit(contact);

        try
        {
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }           

    }
```

**Client (ASP page) code:**

```
    private WebClient client = new WebClient();
    HttpWebRequest req;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1853/PhoneBookService.svc/addentry/");
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
        req.Timeout = 30000;
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }
    protected void btnAddEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var contact = new Contact(); //Contact class from WCF service reference
        contact.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
        contact.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
        contact.PhoneNumber = txtPhone.Text;

        //Code using Webclient
        //client.UploadData(new Uri("http://localhost:1853/PhoneBookService.svc/addentry/"), TToByteArray<Contact>(contact));

        //Code using webrequest
        byte[] buffer = TToByteArray<Contact>(contact);
        req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        Stream PostData = req.GetRequestStream();
        PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        PostData.Close();

        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        StreamReader loResponseStream =
        new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), enc);
        string response = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
    }
    private byte[] TToByteArray<T>(T item)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The type of the argument must be serializable");
        }
        bf.Serialize(ms, item);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

The `Contact` class is defined in the `DataContext`, witch is generated by a LinqToSQL class. I edited the `Contact` class to be serializable.

Comment: Could you point out the exact line of the "Bad Request" exception in your code?

Comment: If you create a web Service that listens for XML formated post requests, it will only respond to XML formated requests. You feed it with binary formated data. I think there is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You created a web service that listens to XML post requests. This implies that the request message Format has to be XML.

Your client on the other Hand serializes the contract in binary Format. Try to use the XMLSerializer, not the BinaryFormatter.

The `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` attribute does not indicate binary data. It only indicates that the message is not wrapped in additional XML tags with meta information.

if you want to receive Binary data in your Service, you should declare the Input Parameter as Stream, then no automatic serialization is done on the Server and you receive the message exactly the way the client sent it.